# Styling basic elements instead of using DIV

Tags: css, styles, element

I'm new to HTML & CSS and have a question concerning the use of basic elements such as header, h1, hgroup, ul, p, etc, and how they are styled.

My project is a simple one page website with little content and mostly design and effects. I have done all of my styling by just selecting basic elements like h1, p, ul, and so forth. Is this ok to do, or should I be using DIVS with class or ID?

Comment: Currently the standard approach is to do all your styling with css. Use html only for basic structure.

Comment: From what I understand the OP used html for structure and css for styling.  He is asking if it is necessary to use divs and classes and ids (which it isn't).

Comment: You can also learn on here http://www.way2tutorial.com/css/tutorial.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion is if it works and suits your needs then what you have done is fine.  You might gain some flexibility if you wish to expand your website by using classes.  Otherwise I would say how you did it is great.

I try to only use IDs when absolutely necessary for javascript or CSS.  That is only when one element needs to be styled or handled in a unique way, otherwise if you can use classes then you maintain consistency and generality (Which are always good).

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. Since I am kind of new to learning this stuff, semantically correct HTML is all the rage so I would like to stay true to that. Since I know DIVs are a nuetral element, I would like to steer clear of them if I can. I don't want to catch divitis.